# Commutativity of keyed hashes

Tags: hash, passwords

**Definition**

${H_1}^{K_1}(X)$ means data  $X$ hashed by keyed hashing algorithm $H_1$ with key $K_1$.

**Short question**

Is $H_1^{K_1}(H_2^{K_2}(X))$ equal to $H_2^{K_2}(H_1^{K_1}(X))$?
Is $H_1^{K_1}(H_1^{K_2}(X))$ equal to $H_1^{K_2}(H_1^{K_1}(X))$?

**Long question**

My web application is storing a hashed password in a database. A web service requests for authentication that the user types a password, which is hashed with a random key and then sent to the server. The server thus only sees $H_1^{K_1}(X)$ where $X$ is the password, not the password itself.

I have to compare the client-side hash with the original password.
How can I do that?

Comment: You are rolling your own crypto. Please stop. Use a purpose-designed password hashing algorithm like [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: Normal hash functions don't have this property, though there are some constructions which might have them intentionally. (Note that you should use the password in the key position and hash random data with it, not the other way around.) But as said, use an existing password authentication protocol.

Comment: I guess I done something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For H1=H2 there are one-way functions with that property: $y = g^x \mod p$.

$ (g^{k_1})^{k_2} = g^{k_1 \cdot k_2} = (g^{k_2})^{k_1}$

This property is exploited by the Diffie-Hellman key exchange. One variation of DH used for password based authentication is [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol).

I strongly recommend to use an existing protocol, and not write your own. Implementing SRP is quite easy to get wrong. I'd just use SSL, either with a normal suite (such as ECDHE_RSA) sending the password in plain over that connection, or using a SRP suite(only supported by a few libs, such as GnuTLS).

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't know of any hash functions that maintain that property. The defacto way to securely store user's passwords is to use adaptive hash algorithms like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). Take a look at [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for more details.